# Error Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]' in C# calling stored procedure

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, t-sql, stored-procedures

I have a dropdownlist that gets populated with a varbinary(256) column from SQL Server.  I send the selected value in this dropdownlist to a stored procedure, but I get the error

> Invalid cast from 'System.String' to 'System.Byte[]'.

The C# code is calling a SP that runs this query to return the name and id to the dropdown list.

```sql
SELECT staffID, sAMAccountName,  (sn + ', ' + givenName) AS fullName
FROM staff
WHERE deleteEmployee = 'no' AND recordType = 'staff'
ORDER BY sn
```

I add the parameter as below.

```
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@staffID", SqlDbType.Binary).Value = ddl_staff.SelectedItem.Value;
```

If I go into SQL and execute the SP like below, I get the expected results.

```sql
DECLARE @staffID varbinary(256)
SELECT @staffID = staffID from staff where samaccountname = 'johndoe'
EXECUTE stp_nho_status @staffID
```

What is happening to the data when it is run by the asp.net page; is it converted to a string in the dropdownlist value?  Do I have to convert it somehow?

Comment: If you set a breakpoint and inspect the value of `ddl_staff.SelectedItem.Value`, what do you get?

Comment: have you checked the value of SelectedItem.Value of the dropdowmlist, the value use to be a string in the parameters you need a Binary and youre adding string value,in your query you should convert the SelectedItem.Value to binary, can you checked

Comment: Also, wonder if the parameter should be `SqlDbType.VarBinary` since it's declared as a `varbinary` in your SQL?

Answer (score 1):

You might consider writing a method that converts a `string` to a `byte[]` (which can be converted to a `SqlDbType.VarBinary`):

```
public static byte[] StrToByteArray(string value)
{
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
    return encoding.GetBytes(value);
}
```

Then you could use it like:

```
objCmd.Parameters.Add("@staffID", SqlDbType.VarBinary).Value = 
    StrToByteArray(ddl_staff.SelectedItem.Value);
```

Comment: Does ASP.NET convert the varbinary to a string when it is populated in the dropdownlist?  I tried as you suggested, I returned no results where I expected them.  I inserted the staffID being passed to the SP in a temp table, and it looks different than what would have been coming out of the staff table, some conversion issue?

Comment: Look it up: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.listcontrol.selectedvalue(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Sounds like a conversion problem. What does the inserted value look like compared to the pre-conversion string value?